# Uninstalling or disabling JRebel from NetBeans 8.0.2 on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: java, uninstallation, netbeans-8, jrebel

I'm working on NetBeans 8.0.2 IDE platform, Ubuntu 15.0.4. How to uninstall or disable JRebel?

Answer (score 8):

For Netbean 8.0.2

Tools --> Plugins --> Installed (Check Show details)

[image: Plugin tabs]

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, if you check the 'Show Details' option you don't have to uninstall all `User Installed Plugins`, you can uninstall the specific JRebel one. Otherwise (the "gotcha") it looks like you have to uninstall all `User Installed Plugins`.

Answer (score 4):

> General Case :- The user wants to uninstall a few plugins from the
>   IDE.

To do it, the user opens the Plugin manager and in the Installed tab she checks the check boxes for plugins (s)he wants to uninstall. The plugin manager informs the use that restart will be required. (s)he clicks the Uninstall button and a wizard pops up informing the user again that the IDE will be restarted. In the wizard the user clicks the Uninstall button and the IDE is restarted and plugins are uninstalled.

> You can do the same individually for JRebel plugin and restart the
>   NetBeans IDE.

[image]

[image]

Check [this Netbeans Wiki page](http://wiki.netbeans.org/PluginUninstallation) for more info on plugin uninstallation.

Comment: In my case JRebel wasn't on the list!

Comment: @T.Popović-Then please check the ''Downloaded'' tab in your plugin manager, and repeat the same my dear. Do let me know whether it was solved! And if solved, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

After exploring some time I found the solution. Actually the solution disables the JRebel. 
In the folder: ~/.netbeans/8.0.2/config/Modules there is a file org-zeroturnaround-jrebel-netbeans.xml.
You need to change the file as follows.

The file before disabling JRebel is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD Module Status 1.0//EN"
                        "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/module-status-1_0.dtd">
<module name="org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.netbeans">
    <param name="autoload">false</param>
    <param name="eager">false</param>
    <param name="enabled">true</param>
    <param name="jar">modules/org-zeroturnaround-netbeans.jar</param>
    <param name="reloadable">false</param>
</module>
```

And file after disabling JRabel:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD Module Status 1.0//EN"
                        "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/module-status-1_0.dtd">
<module name="org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.netbeans">
    <param name="autoload">false</param>
    <param name="eager">false</param>
    <param name="enabled">false</param>
    <param name="jar">modules/org-zeroturnaround-netbeans.jar</param>
    <param name="reloadable">false</param>
</module>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply follow these steps:

1. Go to Netbeans plugin manager. (Menu--> Tools --> Plugins)
2. Select the tab named "Installed".
3. Tick the plugin named "User Installed Plugins".
4. Read the description in the right hand side and understand what user plugins are included under that name.
   [Netbeans Plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tddCC.jpg)
5. Uninstall the plugin named "User Installed Plugins".
6. Restart IDE.
7. Reinstall plugins you really needed in "User Installed Plugins".

Comment: If you check the 'Show Details' option you don't have to uninstall all User Installed Plugins (and then reinstall desired ones), you can uninstall specific ones !